# Enumeration embedded in an enumeration in a special way

Tags: enumerate, embedding

I am trying to embed an `enumerate` environment into another one. Everything is fine if I do add not the content between `[]` after the second `begin{enumerate}`. If I do add that, there is a problem: I get a series of `?` as the first line. Anyone, that understand how to fix this problem?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,letterpaper]{article}   
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={(\textbf{Point 1})}, ref={(Point 1)}, leftmargin=2cm]
\item 
    \begin{enumerate}[label={(P\arabic*)},\ref={(P\arabic*)}]
       \item 1 
       \item 2 
    \end{enumerate}   
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two errors:

you should use enumitem instead of enumerate and in the second [] you have a \ref instead of ref.

So the correct example should be:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,letterpaper]{article}   
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={(\textbf{Point 1})}, ref={(Point 1)}, leftmargin=2cm]
\item 
    \begin{enumerate}[label={(P\arabic*)}, ref={(P\arabic*)}]
       \item 1 
       \item 2 
    \end{enumerate}   
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `\usepackage{enumitem}` and not `\usepackage{enumerate}`.